# Avoid having 0 returned by INDEX() displayed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a function returning some values from a different table:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Kommentar];[@[Radnr.]]);"")
```

This works great for most cases, but if there's no information entered into the column in the other table, I get a 0 when I would have preferred the cell to display the same value as the other table, i.e. stay blank.

Is there any good way to do this?

**Current results**

[image]

**Preferred results**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I have this, I either use conditional formatting to hide the 0s or use an `IF` statement:

```
=iferror(if(INDEX(Table2[Kommentar];[@[Radnr.]])="","",INDEX(Table2[Kommentar];[@[Radnr.]]),"")
```

It returns a zero in an instance of the indexed cell being blank, so simply say if the `INDEX` returns blank, then assume blank, else perform the `INDEX` as initially required.

You can also hide 0s under

file -> options -> advanced settings -> display options for this worksheet -> show a zero in cells that have a zero value

Comment: Yeah, this was pretty much what I was planning on doing,  I was hoping there was a way without having to repeat the formula though :-) And I wasn't aware of the third option, that may come in handy in the future, even if it isn't a perfect fit today.